# Sagepay Direct 3D Secure Blank Page Issue

Tags: opayo, omnipay, 3d-secure

I'm trying to implement Omnipay with Sagepay Direct but am really struggling with the 3D Secure bit.

When I post the MD, PaReq and TermUrl to `https://test.sagepay.com/mpitools/accesscontroler?action=pareq` I just get a blank screen.

These previous SO answers suggest removing spaces from the PaReq field solves the issue, but I don't have any spaces in my data.

[SagePay Direct 3DSecure checkout part returning blank page when redirecting out to bank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657082/sagepay-direct-3dsecure-checkout-part-returning-blank-page-when-redirecting-out)

[Sage Pay test server won't load 3D Secure page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39517092/sage-pay-test-server-wont-load-3d-secure-page)

The data returned from the Omnipay method $response->getRedirectData() is

```
"PaReq" => "eJxVUk1TwjAQvfsrGO52mza0lVnCoBxERqcqOuMxpqt0pB8mrRZ/vQkUweTy3svO2+xLcNoVm8EXaZNX5WTIPH84FWe4Wmui+SOpVpPAWzJGvtMgzybDwGcjn7OLmEc8CXnAgmQ0FJjOHuhTYG8krI/HEA7UOmi1lmUjUKrPy8Wd4DwKoxFCT7EgvZiLgPn7HfpuIexlLGVBYqZkRsV2RaZ5pjKrNMJOR1W1ZaO3IgkihAPBVm/EumlqMwaQdW08U1bfmur2dZMrT1Ve+wGGNm/nhvQXIbh6hONF09YhY/27PBNyef308zKLuuXdA0u71DC5DrItj2/uJwiuAjPZkLDxxH4SsgGLx2E85hxhp6Ms3MUEc1P1GGvXYnZycCqgzV5TqQ5zHRhSV1cl2YoA4Q9jRkaJR/dKqdwObtOFbewkhOMgV9cuf9XYSJmLfoecX24DYwnbGzqC4Gqhf1XoP4BF/z7GLxIJvBw="

"MD" => "20150419746483421285"
```

This is the HTML for the form I'm using

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

  <body>
    <form action="https://test.sagepay.com/mpitools/accesscontroler?action=pareq" method="post">
        <input name="MD" value="20150419746483421285" type="hidden">
        <input name="PaReq" value="eJxVUk1TwjAQvfsrGO52mza0lVnCoBxERqcqOuMxpqt0pB8mrRZ/vQkUweTy3svO2+xLcNoVm8EXaZNX5WTIPH84FWe4Wmui+SOpVpPAWzJGvtMgzybDwGcjn7OLmEc8CXnAgmQ0FJjOHuhTYG8krI/HEA7UOmi1lmUjUKrPy8Wd4DwKoxFCT7EgvZiLgPn7HfpuIexlLGVBYqZkRsV2RaZ5pjKrNMJOR1W1ZaO3IgkihAPBVm/EumlqMwaQdW08U1bfmur2dZMrT1Ve+wGGNm/nhvQXIbh6hONF09YhY/27PBNyef308zKLuuXdA0u71DC5DrItj2/uJwiuAjPZkLDxxH4SsgGLx2E85hxhp6Ms3MUEc1P1GGvXYnZycCqgzV5TqQ5zHRhSV1cl2YoA4Q9jRkaJR/dKqdwObtOFbewkhOMgV9cuf9XYSJmLfoecX24DYwnbGzqC4Gqhf1XoP4BF/z7GLxIJvBw=" type="hidden">
        <input name="TermUrl" value="https://www.example.com/payment/auth-return" type="hidden">
        <center><p>Please click button below to Authenticate your card</p><input value="Go" type="submit"></center>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Do you know why I'm getting a blank page? Do I need to transform the data in some way before sending it to Sagepay?

I've tried everything I can think of but am getting nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

ok, so it's magically working now....may have been a problem at Sagepay's end?

In case it's useful for someone else, here's my iFrame code...

```
<iframe src="secure-3d.php?acsURL=<?=$responseUrl?>&PaReq=<?=$responseData['PaReq']?>&MD=<?=$responseData['MD']?>&TermUrl=<?=$responseData['TermUrl']?>" name="secure-3d" id="secure-3d" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

...where 'secure-3d.php' is my self-submitting form as below....

```
<form id="cardToken" name="cardToken" action="<?=$_GET['acsURL']?>" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="MD" value='<?=str_replace(' ','+',$_GET['MD'])?>' />
  <input type="hidden" name="PaReq" value='<?=str_replace(' ','+',$_GET['PaReq'])?>' />
  <input type="hidden" name="TermUrl" value='<?=str_replace(' ','+',$_GET['TermUrl'])?>' />
  <noscript>
    <center><p>Please click button below to Authenticate your card</p><input type="submit" value="Go"/></p></center>
  </noscript>
</form>
<script language="Javascript">
        var form = document.getElementById("cardToken");
        form.submit();
</script>
```

I just pass the PaReq, MD and TermUrl data through to the form in the querystring, then you need to `str_replace` spaces to pluses when creating the hidden fields.

That should do it!

If anyone has any ideas on how to make this better, please comment